# Splitting DataFrames in Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Using Apache Spark 2.0 with pyspark, I have a DataFrame containing 1000 rows of data and would like to split/slice that DataFrame into 2 separate DataFrames;

- The first DataFrame should contain the first 750 rows
- The second DataFrame should contain the remaining 250 rows

Note: a random seed won't suffice, as I intend to repeat this splitting method several times, and want to be in control as to which data is being used for the first and second DataFrame.

I've found the take(n) method to be useful to generate the first result.
But I can't seem to find the right way (or any way for that matter) to get the second DataFrame.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: I've now managed to find a solution by sorting and applying take(n) again. This still feels like a suboptimal solution though:

```
# First DataFrame, simply take the first 750 rows
part1 = spark.createDataFrame(df.take(750))
# Second DataFrame, sort by key descending, then take 250 rows
part2 = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd.sortByKey(False).toDF().take(250))
# Then reverse the order again, to maintain the original order
part2 = part2.rdd.sortByKey(True).toDF()
# Then rename the columns as they have been reset to "_1" and "_2" by the sorting process
part2 = part2.withColumnRenamed("_1", "label").withColumnRenamed("_2", "features")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right to question using take because it draws the data to the driver and then createDataFrame redistributes it across the cluster. This is inefficient and may fail if your driver doesn't have enough memory to store the data.

Here's a solution that creates a row index column and slices on that:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonicallyIncreasingId

idxDf = df.withColumn("idx", monotonicallyIncreasingId())
part1 = idxDf.filter('idx < 750')
part2 = idxDf.filter('idx >= 750')
```